# how to know in react useEffect, if redux-toolkit action is in pending state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have created an `async thunk` in redux using redux-toolkit as follows:

```
export const getMe = createAsyncThunk(`${SLICE_NAME}/me`, async () => {
  return await fetchMe();
});
```

And, in my react `useEffect`, I am dispatching this action:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!token) return;
  if (user) return;

  dispatch(getMe());
}, [dispatch, token, user]);
```

But my `getMe` action is getting dispatched twice.

I know, the reason is the dependencies of `useEffect`.

Even I tried using a state like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!token) return;
  if (user) return;
  if (isLoading) return;

  setIsLoading(true);
  dispatch(getMe()).finally(() => { setIsLoading(false) });
}, [dispatch, token, user]);
```

But still `getMe` action is dispatched twice (looks like nearly at the same time!!)

So, I was thinking of comparing `getMe.pending.something` with `something else`. I don't know the exact piece of puzzle.

If that does not make sense, then please read this code:

```
const res = await dispatch(getMe());
if (getMe.fulfilled.match(res)) {
  // api call was successful
}
```

As you see in above code, without maintaining any extra flags, we know exactly when API call is done and we know if it was successful.

I need something similar from redux-toolkit, that will tell me if action is in pending state.

Comment: Are you using react 18?

Comment: @clod9353 yup!!

Comment: Then that's intentional. It happens only in development in strict mode. You can check the [beta docs](https://beta-reactjs-org-git-effects-fbopensource.vercel.app/learn/synchronizing-with-effects), or if you prefer just google for an article or youtube video for why useEffect runs twice in react 18

Comment: @clod9353 thanks, I will try to remove Strict mode temporarily to check if everything works fine.

Comment: @clod9353 yes you are correct! That looks intentional, I will ignore it for development. If you could post an answer, i will be happy to accept it! Thanks.

Just for the knowledge now, can you please let me know, how can we check if action is in pending state? without using any flags in redux or in react state